# How to write list of list to a file in cgi/python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, file, cgi

I have a list of list :

```
 table = []
 headers = ["JobId", "Name", "Start_Date", "End_Date", "Value"]
 table.append(headers)
 values1 = ['efwef', 'erwerw', '01', '02', 99]
 table.append(values1)
 values2 = ['efwsdfsef', 'erdwerw', '01']
 table.append(values2)
```

The table is a list of list where each list has different length of elements and all elements may be string

index.cgi :

```
print "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt"
print

for row in table:
    for row_values in row:
        if type(row_values) is not str:
            row_values = str(row_values)
        print row_values + '\t'
    print '\n'
```

But this prints :

```
JobId
Name
Start_Date
End_Date
Value

efwef
erwerw
01
02
99
```

.... 
  ....

Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong here ? I tried replacing '\n' and print "#########" still I see:

```
   JobId
    Name
    Start_Date
    End_Date
    Value
##########################
    efwef
    erwerw
    01
    02
    99
##########################
```

even though I didn't add '\n' each element in the list is printing in a new line.

Comment: note that all your values are strings. And even if they weren't you could just do `row_values = str(row_values)` without further testing and performance loss.

Comment: `print` adds a newline. You should consider writing the whole line at once.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Oh.. I was not aware of that. I thought print is just like normal. new to cgi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print` adds a newline. One way to do what you want would be to `print` your lines at once using `str.join` (also: note that all your data are strings, so no need to convert to string)

```
for row in table:
    print("\t".join(row))
```

if you have integers/floats that wouldn't work so:

```
for row in table:
    print("\t".join(map(str,row)))
```

the nice touch with `join` is that it doesn't add a (useless) `\t` at the end of the string and you don't have to handle that manually.

But you can do it in an even simpler way using `csv` module (even with lists of lists of non-strings), in one line:

```
import csv,sys

csv.writer(sys.stdout,delimiter="\t").writerows(table)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the csv it writes to a file but the '\t' doesn't seems to work in csv file. Am I supposed to do add/change the print "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.csv"
print

Comment: tab separated files like the one I'm creating aren't really csv, they're called "tsv" (tab separated files). You could try with semicolon or comma if it's not an issue for you.